# Authenticated request to WP REST API V2 returning 403 error on /users/me

Tags: authentication, plugin-json-api, oauth

I am using WP REST API Version 2.0-beta7 together with WP OAuth Server version 3.1.91

After authenticating with the *User Credentials* grant type, a request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/users?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]` returns data about all users, including their capabilities. This is private data so the access_token obtained during the authenciation flow is valid.

However, using the same access_token and making a request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]` returns the following response:

```
{
  "code": "rest_user_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot view this user",
  "data": {
    "status": 403
  }
}
```

I was expecting the be able to see private data about the logged in user.

I am using Postman to create and send the API calls using the steps described in the [Using Postman and WP REST API](https://wp-oauth.com/knowledge-base/using-postman-and-wp-rest-api/) article from the WP OAuth Server knowledge base.

I appreciate suggestions on why the *users/me* endpoint is returning 403 when /users is returning private data.

Comment: Purged comment thread on policy as unsuited for main site's comments. That's what we have meta for people, please. :)

Comment: The WP API docs provide details common issues which includes [authentication errors with /users/me](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/problems/#authentication-errors-with-users-me)